# Can we popup a window with pinch zoom capability on mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, scale, pinch

While browsing the mobile site, we can't pinch zoom the window size because the pinch zoom function is disabled.

But I want enable the pinch zoom function on a popup window when user click the small image on the site, so that they can pinch zoom that image on the popup window.

Is jQuery or JavaScript can achieve this function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find a jQuery plugin to achieve this action, https://github.com/eightmedia/hammer.js

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be achieved with JavaScript. I have recently done the same thing.

You need to bind to `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` events and use `event.scale` with `transform: scale()` to do it.